# Titlesec doesn't allow me to use nameref

Tags: header-footer, titlesec, nameref

I'm writing an essay and using `fancyhdr`, `nameref` and `titlesec`.
`Nameref`is used to have the `\currentname` of the section in the footer, but I also wanted to make the section names look different and when I used the `titlesec` package, the section name won't be in the footer.

```
\documentclass[natbib]{apa7}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage[big]{titlesec}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\currentname}{\@currentlabelname}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{some}
\lhead{thing}
\cfoot{\currentname}
\rfoot{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\section*{Antecedentes}
somethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomething...
\newpage

\end{document}
```

And if I delete the `titlesec` package then the footer will again have the \currentname. I haven't found anything, but I'm also new to LaTeX so maybe there's something I'm missing. So, if someone know what to do, it'll be great

Comment: Did you try loading `titletoc` in the place of `fancyhdr`?

Comment: Your class errors if I load titlesec. Beside this your \currentname doesn't work reliably anyway as it doesn't take the asynchronous page breaking into account. You should use \markright and \rightmark to fill the footer.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried both ideas but still experimenting, since it was not urgent, I left the document without the footer